# How do Clojure transducers work under the hood?

Tags: clojure

Reading all over (except the clojure source code) it is somewhat hard to fathom how do transducers avoid the usage of intermediate collections, which is supposed to make them more lean and performant.

A related question arises as to whether or not, they assume, that each input transformation is applied to each element of its input *independently* from the other elements of it, a limitation that may exist if transducers were to work by squashing the input transformations on the input collection ― element-by-element.

Do they inspect the code of their input functions to determine how to interweave them such that they yield the correct result of their composition?

Can you please detail how do transducers in clojure work under the hood, in those regards?

Answer (score 5):

> A related question arises as to whether or not, they assume, that each
>   input transformation is applied to each element of its input
>   independently from the other elements of it

They are named [transducers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_transducer) because they may have (implicit) state.

A transducer is a function that takes a reducing function and returns a reducing function.

A reducing function is a function that expects two parameters: an accumulator and an item and returns an updated accumulator.

This is the reducing function which holds the mutable state (if any).

To get transducers you have to understand they work in two times: composition-time then computation-time. That's why they are functions returning functions.

Let's start with an easy reducing function: `conj`.

The transducer returned by `(map inc)` is `(fn [rf] (fn [acc x] (rf acc (inc x))))`. When called with `conj` it returns a function equivalent to `(fn [acc x] (conj acc (inc x)))`.

The transducer returned by `(filter odd?)` is `(fn [rf] (fn [acc x] (if (odd? x) (rf acc x) acc)))`. When called with `conj` it returns a function equivalent to `(fn [acc x] (if (odd? x) (conj acc x) acc)))`. This one is interesting because `rf` (the downstream reducing function is sometimes short-circuited).

If you want to chain these two transducers you just do `(comp (map inc) (filter odd?))` if you pass `conj` to this composite transducer, `(filter odd?)` is going to be the first to wrap `conj` (because `comp` applies functions from right to left). Then the resulting `filtered-rf`function is passed to `(map inc)` which yields a function equiavlent to:

`(fn [acc x] (filtered-rf acc (inc x)))` where `filtered-rf` is `(fn [acc x] (if (odd? x) (conj acc x) acc)))`. If you inline `filtered-rf` you get: `(fn [acc x] (let [x+1 (inc x)] (if (odd? x+1) (conj acc x+1) acc)))`.

As you may see no intermediate collection or sequence is allocated.

For stateful transducers that's the same story except that reducing functions have mutable state (as little as possible and avoid keeping all previous items in it): usually a volatile box (see `volatile!`) or a mutable Java object.

You may also have remarked that in the example items are first mapped then filtered: computations are applied from left to right which seems in contradiction to `comp`. This is not: remember `comp` here composes transducers, fns that wraps reducing fns. So at compoition time the wrapping occurs right to left (`conj` wrapped by the "filtering rf" then by the "mapping rf") but at computation time the wrapping layers are traversed inwards: map, filter and then conj.

There are finicky implementation details to know to implement your own transducers (`reduced`, init and completion arities) but the general idea is the one exposed above.